# ZSH permission denied Mac M1

Tags: php, macos, apple-m1

I have installed php7.4 on my mac using brew
now I want to be able to have it in my path
I need to run `echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/php@7.4/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/php@7.4/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshr`
when I run this I get permission denied even with sudo
I have also given terminal full disk access but this keeps happening
I have tried different solutions from here but I still get permission denied
any help in solving this will be greatly appreciated

Comment: You might have better luck with this over at https://apple.stackexchange.com since it has to do with system permissions.